# SQL to fetch row into column based on con

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

I have a table in a below structure.and i want to create a sql which can fetch record in a specific order.

```html
Name Phone B.Email           P.Email
Jack 12      ab12@test.com   a21@test.com
Ram 12345   null              Ram@test.com
Raja    543     Raj@test.om       null
Rik     122     null    null
```

Output i want in below order

```html
Name Phone         EMAIL   IsPrimary EmailType
Jack 123  ab12@test.com  Y  B
Jack 123  a21@test.com  N  P
Ram 321         Ram@test.com  Y  P
Raja 543  Raj@test.om  Y  B
```

if there is B.Email, then it will be primary, else P.Email will be primary. IF both the emails are null then that record wil not be there in the output.

Comment: I see in our output for Ram IsPrimary is 'N' ...please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
order by phone, name, isprimary desc
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a UNION to get first people with b.email and then those with p.email and CASE to sort out primary and type

```
SELECT name, phone, b.email EMAIL, 'Y' IsPrimary,
    CASE WHEN b.email  IS NULL THEN 'P'
    ELSE 'B' 
    END EmailType
FROM mail
WHERE b.email IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT name, phone,  p.email EMAIL, 
   CASE WHEN b.email IS NULL THEN 'Y'
   ELSE 'N' 
   END IsPrimary,
   CASE WHEN b.email  IS NULL THEN 'P'
   ELSE 'B' 
   END EmailType
FROM mail
WHERE p.email IS NOT NULL 
ORDER BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are close, but I think they all have errors in their output.

Not sure what SQL engine this is, here's my answer for MySQL5.6:

```
SELECT name,
       phone,
       CASE WHEN BEmail IS NOT NULL THEN BEMail ELSE PEmail END as EMAIL,
       'Y' as IsPrimary,
       CASE WHEN BEmail IS NOT NULL THEN 'B' ELSE 'P' END as EmailType
FROM table_name t
WHERE NOT (BEmail IS NULL AND PEmail IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT name, phone, PEmail, 'N', 'P'
from table_name
WHERE BEmail IS NOT NULL
AND PEmail IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Name;
```

Note that I've changed B.Email to BEmail, P.Email to PEMail, and the table is called "table_name".

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22e43/33)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query :

```
create table     Table3
(Name  varchar2(20),
phone number,
"B.mail" varchar2(50),
"P.mail" varchar2(50));

insert into Table3 values ('Jack',12,'ab12@test.com','a21@test.com');
insert into Table3 values ('Ram',12345,null,'Ram@test.com');
insert into Table3 values ('Raja',543,'Raj@test.com',null);
insert into Table3 values ('Rik',122,null,null);

SELECT Name, Phone, COALESCE("B.mail","P.mail") Email, CASE WHEN "B.mail" IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y'  ELSE 'N' END as IsPrimary,CASE WHEN "B.mail" IS NOT NULL THEN 'B'  ELSE 'P' END as EmailType
FROM Table3 t
where "B.mail" IS NOT NULL OR "P.mail" IS NOT NULL 
UNION 
SELECT Name, Phone, COALESCE("P.mail","B.mail") Email, CASE WHEN "P.mail" IS NOT NULL THEN 'N'  ELSE 'Y' END as IsPrimary,CASE WHEN "P.mail" IS NOT NULL THEN 'P'  ELSE 'B' END as EmailType
FROM Table3 t
where "B.mail" IS NOT NULL OR "P.mail" IS NOT NULL
```